# Find supersets of association database table

Tags: sql, mysql, relational-division

I need to find supersets within an association table.

You can consider `bag` to be a collection of `item` records. The relationship between the two is tracked in `bag_item`.

I need to know which `bag`s are supersets of other `bag`s: containing **ALL** the `item`s and possibly one or more additional items.

`bag`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bag A |
| 2 | Bag B |
| 3 | Bag C |
| 4 | Bag D |

`item`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pencil |
| 2 | Pen |
| 3 | Eraser |
| 4 | Marker |

`bag_item` (association table)

| id | bag_id | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 4 |
| 9 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | 2 |
| 11 | 4 | 3 |

**Database: MySQL 8**

I *have* "base" `bag` identifiers and I *want* to get "superset" `bag` identifiers that contain ALL the items in my "base" bag (and more items if present).

If I query for **ALL** bags, the response should look something like this:

| base_bag_id | superset_bag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

But, I also want to be able to filter on the basis of the `base_bag_id`, e.g. 1 & 4.

I've tried something to the effect of the following:

```sql
select distinct base_bag_item.bag_id, superset_bag_item.bag_id
from bag_item as base_bag_item
join bag_item as superset_bag_item on superset_bag_item.item_id = base_bag_item.item_id
where superset_bag_item.bag_id != base_bag_item.bag_id
and base_bag_item.bag_id in (1, 4)
order by base_bag_item.bag_id, superset_bag_item.bag_id
```

However, this query will incorrectly produce bags that contain *at least one* of the quotes from the "base", e.g. `base_bag_id` 1 will have `superset_bag_id` 3 because both bags contain `item_id` 1.

How do I get my desired output?

Comment: that is impossible, when your where has base_bag_item.bag_id in (1, 4) how can your result be 1,3 and 4

Comment: The note above the desired results indicates what should be seen “if I query for all bags”. The (1, 4) where clause is an example of one possible way that I might want to filter the results.

Comment: *I also want to be able to filter on the basis of the base_bag_id, e.g. 1 & 4.* If some bag is a superset for both bug 1 and bug 4 then it is a superset for minimal superset bag which can be easily obtained by mix aтв distinct. I.e. bag 1 contains (1,2), bag 4 contains (1,2,3), their sum is (1,2,1,2,3), thair minimal superset is distinct list (1,2,3). Any bag which is a superset for this set is a superset for given bags list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is classic [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/),** with the multiple divisors tweak (you want to get all bags for *all* other possible bags, not just for one bag).

There are a number of solutions.

---

A simple one, if rather inefficient, is a double `NOT EXISTS`.

```sql
SELECT
  base.id AS base_bag_id,
  s.id AS superset_bag_id
FROM bag base
JOIN bag s
   ON s.id <> base.id
  AND NOT EXiSTS (SELECT 1
    FROM bag_item bi
    WHERE bi.bag_id = base.id
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM bag_item si
        WHERE si.item_id = bi.item_id
          AND si.bag_id = s.id
    )
);
```

---

A more efficient solution is to join everything up using a left-join, then group and check the count for missing values.

```sql
SELECT
  base.bag_id AS base_bag_id,
  s.id AS superset_bag_id
FROM bag_item base
JOIN bag s ON s.id <> base.bag_id
LEFT JOIN bag_item si
   ON si.bag_id = s.id
  AND si.item_id = base.item_id
GROUP BY
  base.bag_id,
  s.id
HAVING COUNT(si.item_id) = COUNT(*);
```

However, performance is still poor with a large number of bags and items. This can be *significantly* improved by limiting the superset bag candidates to those that contain at least one of the items in the base bag.

```sql
SELECT
  base.bag_id AS base_bag_id,
  s.id AS superset_bag_id
FROM bag_item base
JOIN bag s
  ON s.id <> base.bag_id
  AND s.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT overlap_bag_item.bag_id
    FROM bag_item AS base_bag_item_mirror
    JOIN bag_item AS overlap_bag_item
      ON overlap_bag_item.item_id = base_bag_item_mirror.item_id
    WHERE base_bag_item_mirror.bag_id = base.bag_id)
LEFT JOIN bag_item si
  ON si.bag_id = s.id
  AND si.item_id = base.item_id
GROUP BY
  base.bag_id,
  s.id
HAVING COUNT(si.item_id) = COUNT(*);
```

This can then be modified to filter out the base bags that we're interested in, e.g. base bag `id` of 1 or 4.

```sql
SELECT
  base.bag_id AS base_bag_id,
  s.id AS superset_bag_id
FROM bag_item base
JOIN bag s
  ON s.id <> base.bag_id
  AND s.id IN (
    SELECT /*+ NO_SEMIJOIN(MATERIALIZATION) */ DISTINCT overlap_bag_item.bag_id
    FROM bag_item AS base_bag_item_mirror
    JOIN bag_item AS overlap_bag_item
      ON overlap_bag_item.item_id = base_bag_item_mirror.item_id
    WHERE base_bag_item_mirror.bag_id = base.bag_id)
LEFT JOIN bag_item si
  ON si.bag_id = s.id
  AND si.item_id = base.item_id
WHERE base.bag_id IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY
  base.bag_id,
  s.id
HAVING COUNT(si.item_id) = COUNT(*);
```

This solution selectively turns off [semijoin optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/semijoins.html) in MySQL for the superset filtering subquery. When semijoin optimization is enabled, adding the `WHERE base.bag_id IN (1, 4)` statement results in the creation of a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-materialization.html) with all the `bag_item`s in it. This defeats the purpose of the subquery and tanks performance. We avoid this with an [optimizer hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/optimizer-hints.html).

If you switch to `WHERE (base.bag_id = 1 OR base.bag_id = 4)`, semijoin optimization isn't performed on the superset subquery and the hint isn't needed.

When making these kinds of optimization decisions, always check `EXPLAIN` first.

---

If necessary, we can also remove the reference to `bag` by using a window function over the first `bag_item`.

```sql
SELECT
  base.bag_id AS base_bag_id,
  si.bag_id AS superset_bag_id
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY base.bag_id) AS count
    FROM bag_item base
) base
LEFT JOIN bag_item si
   ON si.item_id = base.item_id
  AND si.bag_id <> base.bag_id
GROUP BY
  base.bag_id,
  si.bag_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(base.count);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/vZTpwQkG)

Comment: This definitely works! Unfortunately, the left join solution is still not efficient when there are lots of bags since the query combines the base bag with all other bags. Ideally we could filter the bags we attempted to evaluate against the base to those that had at least one shared item, prior to counting.

Comment: Ultimately you need to evaluate all items in one bag against all in the other. You could avoid querying `bag` at all by using a window function https://dbfiddle.uk/tm7wEtgH

Comment: For very large sets of items per bag, the double `NOT EXISTS` might make more sense instead.

Comment: @Charlieface, the **Relational Division With Remainder** article is a great read. The code used in the examples sticks to ANSI SQL standards so the protability is not an issue for popular RDBMS such as MySQL. Thank you,sir.

Comment: @JaredPetersen your edit is interesting. `DISTINCT` is not necessary in a semi-join anyway, not sure why it's there and maybe that's why you needed an optimizer hint. You could also push the `WHERE` predicate into the inner query. See also https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/ for further techniques

Comment: @Charlieface The `DISTINCT` was intended to ensure that bags don't show up multiple times in the subquery. Although, that's not really necessary since it's part of an `IN` statement. I tried removing `DISTINCT` and the semijoin is still performed (and performance is still poor) without the hint. In any case, thanks a ton for your answer here! I just wanted to share what I had found while still giving you credit for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution please:

```
SELECT 
    base_bag.bag_id AS base_bag_id, 
    superset_bag.bag_id AS superset_bag_id
FROM 
    (SELECT bag_id FROM bag_item GROUP BY bag_id) base_bag
JOIN 
    (SELECT bag_id FROM bag_item GROUP BY bag_id) superset_bag
ON base_bag.bag_id <> superset_bag.bag_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT item_id 
    FROM bag_item base_items 
    WHERE base_items.bag_id = base_bag.bag_id 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bag_item superset_items
        WHERE superset_items.bag_id = superset_bag.bag_id 
        AND superset_items.item_id = base_items.item_id
    )
)
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) FROM bag_item WHERE bag_id = superset_bag.bag_id
) > (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) FROM bag_item WHERE bag_id = base_bag.bag_id
)
ORDER BY base_bag_id, superset_bag_id;
```

Comment: this yields nothing see https://dbfiddle.uk/TClVW6gk

Comment: I have edited the query and tested it. Can you please try it?

Answer (score 0):

> But, I also want to be able to filter on the basis of the base_bag_id, e.g. 1 & 4.

Assuming that this means "find a bug which contains all items for each specified bag":

```
SET @base_bags = '1,4';
```

```
WITH 
minimal_superset AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT item_id
  FROM bag_item
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(bag_id, @base_bags)
  ),
bags_list AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT bag_id
  FROM bag_item
  )
SELECT @base_bags base_bags_list, bag_id superset_bag_id
FROM minimal_superset
CROSS JOIN bags_list
LEFT JOIN bag_item USING (bag_id, item_id)
GROUP BY bag_id
HAVING NOT SUM(bag_item.item_id IS NULL)
```

| base_bags_list | superset_bag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1,4 | 2 |
| 1,4 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2s35d2yP)

If the bags in the list must be not included into the superset bags list (bag #4 in the example) then add `WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(bag_id, @base_bags)` to CTE `bags_list`.

Comment: Apologies here -- the intent by that was to indicate that I wanted to also be able to get the results for a subset of the base_bags. For example, "show me bags that are supersets of base bag 1, supersets of base bag 4 (`while base_bag_id in (1, 4)`). It wasn't intended to be a list situation.